# Find a $\lambda$ so the system has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\begin{align}
    3x + \lambda y & = 5 + \lambda \\
    2x + 5y & = 8
\end{align}
$$

I got that $\lambda$ can be anything by using Cramer's rule, so there are infinite solutions.

Comment: @MJD How did you write that lambda?

Comment: In between `$...$`, the web site will render mathematics.  In this case, I wrote `$\lambda$`.  [There's a tutorial here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Also, if you edit the question again, you'll see exactly how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple idea would be.

Try out a geometrical representational of the two equation(They are of course a linear equation in two variable). It would be a straight line.

*So, when does two straight line have a unique solution?

> When they intersect exactly at one point

*When does it does not have a unique solution

> When two equations are same(then there exists unique number of solutions)
>
> When two equations are parallel(then there exists no solution):General form of two parallel lines $ax+by+c=0$ and $ax+by+d=0$ where $c\neq d$

So the problem is to simple neglect values of $\lambda$ that satisfies the above two conditions.

Take ratio of coefficients $\frac{3}{2}=\frac{\lambda}{5}$ gives $\lambda=\frac{15}{2}$. This is the condition for those lines to be parallel.(In this case both equations can't be equal as if we substitute $\lambda =\frac{15}{2}$ . These are not equal(look at the constant).

Hence the solution for unique solution is $\boxed{\lambda \neq \frac{15}{2}}$

Answer (score 2):

Calculate
$$\det \left( \begin{matrix} 3 & \lambda \\ 2 & 5 \end{matrix} \right)$$
There is a unique solution whenever that determinant is nonzero.

Comment: So lambda is anything except 7.5, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a unique solution, the two equations must be independent (so that they represents two different straight lines and would intersect at a point). Since, you have applied Cramer's rule, the condition is $$\det \left( \begin{matrix} 3 & \lambda \\ 2 & 5 \end{matrix} \right)\ne0.$$

Comment: What does it mean for two lines when the determinant is 0? They do not intersect?

Comment: Yes, they must be a scalar multiple of the other i.e., they are parallel.

Comment: What does it mean if D=0 and Dx and Dy <>0, and what if all of them are 0?

Comment: I already answered what is meant by $D=0$. But I don't understand what you meant by $Dx$.

Comment: I don't know what Dx and Dy represent, but I know that you get them by replacing the x and y colon with the solutions of the equations.

Comment: Now, I understand what you meant. So, in this case $Dx$ is $\det \left( \begin{matrix} 5+\lambda & \lambda\\ 8 & 5 \end{matrix} \right)$, right? If, it is so, then $Dx=0$ will imply $x=0$ is a solution (and similarly for $y$), provided $D\ne0$.